# Motion blur not apply on every frame

Tags: motion-blur

as you can see motion blur is not apply on frame 29(left image), and apply on frame 30 (right image) it does happen randomly on the following frame, i am using particle system that i export to alambic file and try to render it with motion blur, i realize that the particle sometimes stop but id try to make it having movement using noise texture but nothing changes

[image]